# Password Protection of file in android

Tags: android, encryption, password-protection

I would like to give some kind of protection to my files either stored in SDCard or in application sandbox. Currently I am using Cipher to encrypt or decrypt any file. Problem with using Cipher is time. It takes lots of time if file is large. Like currently I am encrypting a video file which takes more than 4 minutes to decrypt. I want to know that Can we apply some kind of password protection to file without encrypting ? If anyone knows how can we do that, please let me know.

Comment: your encrypt or decrypt way is best... or you can save data in app's internal storage. in external there is not better way then encrypt or decrypt

Comment: Bear in mind that if you are encrypting files using *your own password*, baked into your app, that this is useless, as anyone who wants to can just get the password and decrypt the files. If you are encrypting files using a password *from the user*, this can be useful to defend the *user's* data from others.

Comment: Oh ya, I will ask user to configure the password. And Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is NO. That is not possible. File is on SD card stored as "array of 1 and 0" so each program can access SD card and read your data. Encryption is best way to keep your data secret.