# How to create a .txt file with password protection in android programatically?

Tags: android, file, password-protection

I am creating .txt file in android by using below Snippet

```
public void createTextFile(String fileName) {
try {
    File notesDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Text Files");
    if (!notesDirectory.exists()) {
        notesDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    File textFile = new File(notesDirectory, fileName);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(textFile);
    writer.append("Sample Content");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Created at "+textFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Added below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is it possible to provide password for that .txt file programatically in Android?

Comment: I think you have to encrypt your files content with a password. You cant "lock" the file itself with a password

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742091/password-protection-of-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jasypt.
http://www.jasypt.org/

Below the example.

```
StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
String encryptedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(userPassword);
...
if (passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(inputPassword, encryptedPassword)) {
  // correct!
} else {
  // bad login!
}

...encrypting and decrypting a text...

StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
textEncryptor.setPassword(myEncryptionPassword);
String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt(myText);
...
String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
```